# How do I make a function accept any type (not necessarily an object)?

Tags: java

I have a function

```
boolean isValid(/* what goes in here? */) {  
     //do stuff  
}
```

In the function signature, what do I have to enter in the parameter list in order for the method to accept a single parameter that may be of any type (primitive or object)?

I have searched around on this site and google, but I could only find situations where the return type is unknown.

Comment: How would you do anything with it if you don't know what it is?

Comment: I would check the type in the body.

Comment: And then what? Generate 100 different cases depending on the type? Why don't you just overload the function?

Comment: There is only one valid type, so I can return false if it's not that type (in addition to other validation).

Comment: If there is only valid type then write the method to only accept that type. It sounds like you are used to dynamically typed languages. Java is not.

Comment: But what if the caller uses an invalid type? I don't want a 'function not found' exception, but the exception in the isValid() body.

Comment: This is bad idea but you have right to learn from mistakes so if you really want to complicate your life then just use Object type. BTW if you pass primitive type it will be autoboxed first so int will become Integer and so on.

Comment: How would it generate a function not found exception? The program wouldn't compile if this was case. You are trying to make a compile time error into a runtime exception. I would prefer the compile time error over the runtime exception.

Comment: There are external calls to my functions, I can't confirm what other people will be passing in before the thing will be compiled and run.

Comment: Can you please explain why you prefer to throw exception at runtime over a compile-time error?

Comment: Short answer: The person who unit tests does not want compile-time errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the function accept the generic object type, Java will create an object version of any primitive data type (i.e. Integer for int).

Answer (score 1):

Reading the question and the comments, it seems like your perception of how compiled languages work may be a bit off.

If you make your function accept only one type (e.g. String), then it will fail to compile if the caller does not pass an object that is an instance of that type.  "Not compiling" means they *will not even be able to run the program* without fixing the error.  The compiler enforces this type safety for you, so you don't have to worry about this.

Comment: Eh, ish. It's not too hard to imagine a framework that uses reflection and complains if it can't find a suitable overload.

Comment: (a) I somehow doubt that's the problem the OP is trying to solve... (b) The caller needs to take the responsibility to understand the libraries they're using (especially if it's something as trivial as this)

Comment: There is a misunderstanding here: I don't want whoever will use the code in the future to run into a compile-time error if that person uses an incorrect type. I want to throw the exception in the body at runtime (even if compile time errors are easy to fix). So my choices are to either make the param accept anything (see jtoomey or Pshemo) or to validate the type everywhere without reusing isValid()

Comment: Java is a statically typed language. Why are you trying to turn it into a dynamically typed one? I suspect it'll make nobody happy: the Java folks will want their type checking, and the dynamic-type folks will wonder why you don't just use jython, jruby, groovy or any other dynamically-typed JVM-based languages.

Comment: Type safety exists exactly for this reason.  As a developer, I would much rather have a compile-time error and fix it immediately than get failures later (potentially after user-visible errors) and have to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the best practices, but I'm in a special situation here (I won't go into the details), so I'll go with the frowned-upon option.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are a bit confused. 
I will try to clarify some things:

- You probably know that the return type of a method is the value that will be pass to the part of the code that called that method(aka know as client). Every method/function in Java can only return only one type(I assume you are familiar with basic polymorphism and you know what an IS A relationships is...). Here is the first clarification, you can return only one type, but one or many objects(There are data structure types).
- Arguments are the values that the caller/client of the method/function can pass into the it for processing. Arguments can have zero or many parameters, this mean that you can pass as many objects as you want.
- Parameters are exactly the same as arguments it is just a terminology difference nothing else. I you want to be accurate with the terms, you can say that parameters are the brackets when you define the method and argument are those brackets when you call the method.
- In either the return type or in the parameters/arguments, the 2 types of types you can pass are Objects or primitive types. 
  If you use something of type Object, this will allow you to return any object(Object is the super class of all classes). But primitive types are not objects, so a type Object in a signature will not allow you to pass a number, but there is one little trick...
  In Java there are special types of Objects known as primitive wrappers(Integer,Double...) this objects are object representations of primitives, sometimes they are used because they have some inbuilt functions that help programmers to easily manipulate the data(That is not the main point, keep reading...),every wrapper that represents a numerical primitive type, extends a class called Number and because of one feature that Java have known as autoboxing, you can pass primitives into Wrappers automatically.

Anyway, I don't know if this is the trick you were looking for, but in any case I want just to advice you, that there is no reason at all to do what you are trying, It sounds really strange and I don't think that such thing is really needed in real life programming.

Have a look at this code :

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    App app = new App();
    app.method(5);
}

public void method(Number number) {
    System.out.print(number);
}
```

Another alternative: 
Another example that I can think about in order to make a parameter universal is by the use of generics. So just for ending this answer to prove my point, here a method that will allow you pass anything you want, no mater if is primitive or object:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.method(5);

        app.someMethod(9);
        app.someMethod("Whatever");
        app.someMethod(true);
    }

    public void method(Number number) {
       System.out.println(number);
    }

    public <T> void someMethod(T t) {
       System.out.println(t);
    }

}
```

I hope you find this useful, but I insist that I doubt that you will never do something like this in real life.

Comment: The <T> in "public <T> void someMethod(T t) {}" refers to the paramter type, not the return type, right? THanks

Comment: @Wuschelbeutel Kartoffelhuhn The <T> doesn't refer to the return type, because the return type in that method is void. It means that that method uses a Generic parameter. Java doesn't know for an object of type 'T' so it is just a way to mark that it is a generic parameter.

Answer (score 1):

After reading through the comments it seems like you have a business need to valid any object people pass to you, and possibly, you will have to support more types as time goes on.

The simplest solution is like what jtoomey said, make a method like `public boolean isValid(Object val)`. However, think about how much if statements you have to write, and how hard is it to modify the code when new type validation are needed.

To me, I would probably do something bit more complicated than just providing a single method. I would leverage factory to create validator base on class type like:

```
public interface Validator<T> {

   public boolean isValid(T val) {
   }
}

public class ValidatorFactory {

    public static ValidatorFactory create(String configFile) {
         /*read config and create new instance */
    }

    public Validator<T> createValidator(Class<T> clazz) {
         /* base on config and create validator base on type*/
    }
} 


public class Application {

    public static ValidatorFactory vFactory = ValidatorFactory.create() 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         Object val = Arguments.getVal(); //assume this exists

         Validator<Object> validator = vFactory.create(val.class);
         if (validator == null) {
            System.out.println("not valid");
            return;
         }

         System.out.println(validator.isValid());
    }
}
```

Note that personally I feel this is a terrible solution, because you are throwing away the type safe feature of Java. But if you really must, having a configurable factory would be better than just a method that takes in any type. Having the `Validator` interface allows you to know the type when you are writing validation code.